# Windows Hello on Surface Pro 4 troubles

Tags: windows-hello

Bizarre chain of events, but maybe someone can help.  I have a docked Surface Pro 4 and I setup Windows Hello on it.  That seemed to disable the onboard ethernet.  I resorted to using wifi until I had time to look at it.  I took the machine remote for a bit, came back, and plugged it in again.  The network connection came back up, but now Windows Hello does not work.  Attempting to use Windows Hello, the camera never comes on and it flips to the PIN entry screen after about 15 seconds.

Any ideas?  So far I've tried the Hello "improve recognition" task.  It sees the camera during that process, but still doesn't use it during login.

Comment: Have you verified, that the permissions to your Camera, are configured properly and you have given authorization so Windows can use it?

Comment: @Ramhound Camera access is on. I don't see a specific app level switch for Hello.  Someplace else I should check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fixed itself during a Windows update